Pause Nautilus search and freeze results when satisfied, without clearing them
Context
I am searching a certain file by name through many folders, but often I can catch the right result at a glance at the Location column. There, I want to open location for that result, except the long search keeps running, adding more and more results, often inserting them above the match I wanted, causing my match to go lower and lower in the list of files.
This is quite annoying as I already found what I wanted, and now I need to scroll down in order to find my file, as if I'm racing against the search, and all of that while consuming CPU for nothing.
I tried to pause the search by clicking on the search field delete icon, and on the magnifier glass button, but both clear the search and its results entirely, so I can't see the files I wanted.
Question
Is there any way to pause a search in Nautilus, so I can see all the results found so far and click on them?
Notes
Alternatively, an option to prevent insert new results above existing ones (only appending them at the bottom) would do the trick, but that's another question and it wouldn't fix the useless CPU usage issue.

Would you consider a command line technique to find that file?  Once found, you'd simply enter Ctrl-C to stop the search.  I'm thinking of the find command here.

This can be a valid feature request to the developpers of nautilus.

What version are you running? In 46, the stop button only stops search and doesn't remove the results.
